# Tabulating groups by row and column in R, WITHOUT looping

Tags: r, matrix, group-by, dplyr

Please feel free to edit the title if there is a more clear one.  Here is what I am trying to do.

Without looping (because the dimensions of the matrix will be very large and loops are too slow.)

Given this matrix, A

```
  A = rbind(
    c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2  ),
    c(2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2  ),
    c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1  ),
    c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1  ),
    c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1  ),
    c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2  ),
    'S'=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))

A = cbind(A,'R'=c(rep(1:2,3),NA))  

                 R
  2 2 1 1 2 2 2  1
  2 2 3 2 2 3 2  2
  1 1 1 2 2 1 1  1
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1  2
  1 2 1 1 1 1 1  1
  2 2 1 1 1 1 2  2
S 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 NA
```

We have the bottom row called “S” and the last column called “R”

I want to group by R and S and basically return a TABLE () function of each group, for example,

```
S=1, R =1

         R
  **2**  1

  **1**  1

  **1**  1

S   1
```

The tricky part is when not all values show up, I still need it to tabulate 0 for the third.  (So perhaps I need some workaround)...
Basically, the table would return:

```
1 2 3
2 1 0 

I would like the resulting thing to be 

(R * S) x 3 


And the output would be:

2 1 0
1 2 0 
3 0 0 
2 1 0 
1 2 0 
2 1 0 
2 1 0 
1 2 0 
1 2 0 
2 0 1
2 1 0 
2 1 0 
2 0 1
1 2 0
```

Comment: Sorry, the first column was bolded in my other processor, is it clear now?

Comment: What is il with the down votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subset the 'A' matrix by removing the last column and last row to create the 'A1', change the rownames and column names with the last column/row, `melt` to 'long' format, convert to `data.table`, `dcast` it to 'wide' (after getting the number of rows or just use the `fun.aggregate` as `length` in `dcast`)

```
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)
A1 <- A[-nrow(A), -ncol(A)]
row.names(A1) <- A[-nrow(A),"R"]
colnames(A1) <- A["S", - ncol(A)]
dcast(setDT(melt(A1))[,.N ,.(RowCol = paste(Var2, Var1, sep="_"), value)], 
              RowCol~value,value.var="N", fill = 0)
#    RowCol 1 2 3
# 1:    1_1 2 1 0
# 2:    1_2 1 2 0
# 3:    2_1 1 2 0
# 4:    2_2 1 2 0
# 5:    3_1 3 0 0
# 6:    3_2 2 0 1
# 7:    4_1 2 1 0
# 8:    4_2 2 1 0
# 9:    5_1 1 2 0
#10:    5_2 2 1 0
#11:    6_1 2 1 0
#12:    6_2 2 0 1
#13:    7_1 2 1 0
#14:    7_2 1 2 0
```

Or if we don't need to `paste` the  row/column names

```
dcast(setDT(melt(t(A1))), Var1+Var2~value, length)
```

---

Or we can use `table` from `base R` after converting to 'long' format with `rep`

```
table(data.frame(RowCol = paste(rep(colnames(A1), nrow(A1)), 
             rep(rownames(A1), ncol(A1)), sep = "_"), c(A1)))
```

Comment: Could I ask........what if in the original table we never observe a "3", but we still want it considered in the tabulation?

Comment: @robertevansanders  You can convert the `c(A1)` to `factor` with `levels` specified as `1:3` and then do the `table`

Comment: Something like this? A1 = as.factor(A1,levels=c('1','2','3'))?  What do you mean c(A1)

Comment: @robertevansanders I meant it for the second soltuion, where we are converting the matrix to a vector with `c`

Comment: I still get this error: Error in as.factor(c(A1), levels = as.character(1:3)) : 
  unused argument (levels = as.character(1:3))

Comment: @robertevansanders  I think it should be `factor(c(A), levels = 1:3)`

Comment: Any way to do this with the dcast option?

Comment: @robertevansanders  You can convert to `factor` as I specified above and then use `drop=FALSE` in the `dcast`

Comment: Like this? dcast(setDT(melt(t(factor(c(A1), levels = 1:3)))), Var1+Var2~value, length, drop=F)

Comment: @robertevansanders  I meant to change the `value` column to `factor` after `melt`ing i.e. `dcast(setDT(melt(A1))[, value := factor(value, levels  = 1:3)], Var1+ Var2 ~value, length, drop = FALSE)`